# How to increase timeout when import data into Acumatica using webservices API

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a problem when trying to import some data from client application into Acumatica system using web Services API. I try to send data in screen Bill And Adjusment (AP301000) and use much data in detail transactions. Data in transaction are about 235 rows. The error message when I try to import data is "The Operation Has Timeout".

I have tried to change web.config file like this below :

```
  <httpRuntime 
     executionTimeout="36000".../>

  <compilation
     debug="false".../>

  <sessionState
     timeout="360".../>
```

This below is my code,
I used button to do the process and then call method in another class :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using JADEACCU.services;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace JADEACCU
    {
        public partial class frmTest : Form
        {
            ServicesConnection con = new ServicesConnection();
            COMClass comClass = new COMClass();

            services.Screen context = new services.Screen();
            servicesUntyped.Screen contextUntyped = new servicesUntyped.Screen();

            public frmTest()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void btnSendBill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string type, refNbr, dtdate, customerOrder, customer, terms, currency, dtDueDateString, dtCashDiscDateString, description, jadeRefNbr;

                type = cmbType.Text;
                refNbr = txtRefNbr.Text;
                dtdate = dtDate.Text.ToString();
                customerOrder = txtCustomerOrder.Text;
                customer = txtCustomer.Text;
                terms = cmbTerms.Text;
                currency = cmbCurrency.Text;
                dtDueDateString = dtDueDate.Text.ToString();
                dtCashDiscDateString = dtCashDiscDate.Text.ToString();
                description = txtDescription.Text;
                jadeRefNbr = txtJadeRefNbr.Text;

                comClass.InsertBill(jadeRefNbr, dtdate, customerOrder, description, customer, terms, currency, dtDueDateString, dtCashDiscDateString);
            }
        }
  }
```

call this method :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Data.Sql;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using JADEACCU.services;

    namespace JADEACCU
    {
        public class COMClass
        {
            ServicesConnection sCon = new ServicesConnection();
            services.Screen context = new services.Screen();
            servicesUntyped.Screen contextUntyped = new servicesUntyped.Screen();

            public string InsertBill(string vBillNo, string vBillDate, string vVendorRef, string vDesc, string vVendCode, string vTerms, string vCcy, string vDueDate, string vCashDiscDate)
            {
                //sCon.getLogin(context);
                sCon.getLoginBill(context);

                AP301000Content konten = context.AP301000GetSchema();
                List<Command> oCmds = new List<Command>();

                //Create Header.
                //oCmds.Add(konten.Actions.Insert);
                oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = "Bill", LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.Type });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = "0000", LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.ReferenceNbr });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = vBillNo, LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.JadeRefNbr });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = vBillDate, LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.Date });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = vVendorRef, LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.VendorRef });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = vDesc, LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.Description });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = vVendCode, LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.Vendor });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = vTerms, LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.Terms });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = vCcy, LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.Currency });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = vDueDate, LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.DueDate });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = vCashDiscDate, LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.CashDiscountDate });

        //oCmds.Add(konten.Actions.Save);

        string serverDb, userDb, passDb, databaseDb;
        serverDb = Properties.Settings.Default.serverDB;
        databaseDb = "SGL";
        userDb = "jade";
        passDb = "jade1234";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

        con.ConnectionString = @"server=" + serverDb + "; database=" + databaseDb + "; user=" + userDb + "; password=" + passDb + ";";
        //con.ConnectionString = "Provider = SQLOLEDB.1; Persist Security Info = False; Server = 192.168.10.7; Initial Catalog = SGL; User ID = jade; Password = jade1234";
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("select case when a.branchid = '0102' then 'KARAWANG' else 'CIKARANG' end as BranchID, " +
                                "BookingNo, b.RAccount as ICharges, BCostUnit, IQty, BCost, " +
                                "case when TaxSts = 'Y' and c.TaxRate = 10 then 'PPN' when TaxSts = 'Y' and c.TaxRate = 1 then 'PPN1' end as TaxID, " +
                                "case when isnull(WhseCode,'') = 'WH01' and a.branchid = '0101' then left(rcontcode,4) + 'C1' + right(rcontcode,2) when isnull(WhseCode, '') = 'WH02' and a.branchid = '0101' then left(rcontcode, 4) + 'C2' + right(rcontcode, 2) when isnull(WhseCode, '') = 'WH03' and a.branchid = '0101' then left(rcontcode, 4) + 'C3' + right(rcontcode, 2) when isnull(WhseCode, '') = 'WH04' and a.branchid = '0101' then left(rcontcode, 4) + 'C4' + right(rcontcode, 2) when isnull(WhseCode, '') = 'KLC' and a.branchid = '0102' then left(rcontcode, 4) + 'K1' + right(rcontcode, 2) when isnull(WhseCode, '') = 'GIIC' and a.branchid = '0105' then left(rcontcode, 4) + 'GL' + right(rcontcode, 2) when isnull(WhseCode, '') = 'TLC' and a.branchid = '0106' then left(rcontcode, 4) + 'TL' + right(rcontcode, 2) when isnull(WhseCode, '') = '' and a.branchid = '0101' then left(rcontcode, 4) + 'HO' + right(rcontcode, 2) when isnull(WhseCode, '') = '' and a.branchid = '0102' then left(rcontcode, 4) + 'KO' + right(rcontcode, 2) when isnull(WhseCode, '') = '' and a.branchid = '0103' then left(rcontcode, 4) + 'CO' + right(rcontcode, 2) when isnull(WhseCode, '') = '' and a.branchid = '0104' then left(rcontcode, 4) + 'PO' + right(rcontcode, 2) end as SubAccount from BookRates as a inner join revcodes as b on a.icharges = b.rcode inner join billmaster as c on a.billno = c.billno where a.BillNo = '" + vBillNo + "'", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dR in dt.Rows)
        {
            oCmds.Add(konten.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow);
            oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = dR["BranchID"].ToString(), LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.Branch });
            oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = dR["BookingNo"].ToString(), LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.JobOrderNbr });
            oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = dR["ICharges"].ToString(), LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.InventoryID });
            oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = dR["BCostUnit"].ToString(), LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.UnitCost });
            oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = dR["SubAccount"].ToString(), LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.Subaccount });
            oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = dR["IQty"].ToString(), LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.Quantity });
            oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = dR["BCost"].ToString(), LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.Amount });
            oCmds.Add(new Value { Value = dR["TaxID"].ToString(), LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.TaxCategory, Commit = true });
        }
        oCmds.Add(konten.Actions.Save);

        try
        {
            context.AP301000Submit(oCmds.ToArray());
            return "ACUMATICA - Save Bill SUCCESS";
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
            //return "ACUMATICA - Save Bill FAILED";
        }
    }
  } 
 }
```

But it still doesn't work.
Please give some reference how to solve this case.
Thanks

Comment: Where do you get timeout? Is this a client timeout or server timeout?

Comment: i don't know exactly, but i got this error timeout in client application when this client app try to do the import process to acumatica system

Comment: Without knowing where the timeout happens there's little we can do to help. What's your client application? What kind of control do you have over it?

Comment: its simple client application, developed by C# language, what do you mean with kind of control ? sorry i don't understand..

Comment: Was it you who developed the application? Can you show the code and exact exception?

Comment: Yes, of course, I have edited my questions and already post the codes, The error message of Time Out shows when call context.AP301000Submit(oCmds.ToArray());

Comment: Please give exact exception, with stack trace.

Comment: I have fixed this issue, not about the timeout actually. it's because of I try to import JobOrderNbr in detail transactions doesn't not exist in the system. I don't know why I get error "Timeout".

Thanks for your response Serg Rogovtsev

Answer (score 0):

when you create the screen object, there is an option to set the timeout. Try setting that value to infinite.

sample

```
context = new Screen();
context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
context.Url = "http://blah blah";
context.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
```

Comment: i have tried to set the timeout like this : context.Timeout = 1000000; , but I will try your suggestions

Comment: as @serg Rogovtsev asked, please give more detail about your exception and on what exact line are you getting the exception.

Comment: mark exact line where you get exception and the whole exception text.

Comment: Didnt see your code using the line i suggested.. ;) or did you use and is it is not working. so, you removed it? as others mention you should be more exact on the problem. otherwise we cant understand easily.

Comment: I have fixed this issue, not about the timeout actually. it's because of I try to import JobOrderNbr in detail transactions doesn't not exist in the system. I don't know why I get error "Timeout".

After I add JobOrderNbr in the system and try to import again, it works..

thank you for your response guys.. :)